# Magento Order Export with custom attribute Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, custom-attributes

Currently the order export dump only provides

`Order #    Purchased On    Bill to Name    Ship to Name    G.T. (Base)    G.T. (Purchased)    Status`

We need to add to this,

`Invoice Number, SKU, HSN Code (custom attribute), Quantity, Tracking Number,  Product Tax Code, Ship to City, Ship to PinCode, Order Type (Prepaid or COD), Customer Email, Customer Phone, Subtotal, Discount, Shipping, Grand Total`

[image: current imported fields]

Any suggestion that which file is responsible or any method.

UPDATE: I used this module but this module don`t show custom attributes.

[extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-import-export-orders-to-csv-1.html)

**Any one knows which files are responsible for rendering the csv in default magento**

Thank You.

Comment: did you find an extension to help you with this?

Comment: No , but I think I did custom work in that project.